# Need jSpinner to be enabled from jRadioButton

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jradiobutton, jspinner

I am working in a JTabbedPane inside of a JFrame.  I have a jRadioButton that I need when selected to activate/enable two jSpinner controls that select date & time. I cannot find a reference for how this should be completed and this is not a school project.

I need the jSpinner to be disabled while jRadioButton is clear and enabled while selected.  The jRadioButton is part of a ButtonGroup of two buttons.  The other jRadioButton when enabled will open a jTextField to enter data.

Any help or links to documentation will be helpful.  Everything I have found so far doesn't describe how to link these two.

Thanks

Comment: Start [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html); enable/disable the spinner in the button's listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a Listener on your radio buttons.  Here is a simple example for the JRadioButton controlling the JSpinner.  Of course you'd want to add some logic/another listener to handle your other components as well, (the JTextField etc).

Hope this helps!

```
    final JRadioButton spinnerButton = new JRadioButton("Spinner Enabled");
    spinnerButton.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            if (spinnerButton.isSelected()){
                spinner.setEnabled(true);
            } else {
                spinner.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: a changeListener is not what to use (it's notifying rather unspecifically about a bunch of changes) Instead, use an ActionListener or an ItemListener

Comment: @SuicideClyde Thank you for that snippet, it helped me with another step in this situation.

Comment: @kleopatra The Snippet helped with enabling/setting visible to the spinners and textfield associatted with buttons but I did it in the Action listeners.  The snippet just gave me the idea.

Comment: @kleopatra good point on the listener type to use.  I've updated the answer above with an ItemListener which I think better suits the situation in question.